# Edit commit message in a Bitbucket squash merge

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Is there a way to edit the commit message in a Bitbucket squash merge? I really don't like how commit messages usually look by default after a squash merge. The title doesn't say anything about the subject of the commit and often times some commit messages are only relevant to the reviewers of the PR and can be safely discarded or summarized into a more coherent commit message. Is there any way to do this besides doing it locally and pushing that into the PR?

Comment: I don't think so. Doing it locally and force pushing will likely be your best option.